# Detach Python Selenium from Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver, gunicorn

I'm fairly new to gunicorn, Is there any possible way that allow me to run selenium browser outside of gunicorn enviroment?

For example, I would like to update my Django application without interfering with a running selenium driver in the background.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def selenium(request):
    options = Options()

    options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

    chrome_path = "chrome/driver/chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(executable_path=chrome_path) ,options=options)

    driver.get('https://example.com/')

    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Selenium driver will stay active until, I restart gunicorn to update my code. Is there any other way to do so without driver shutting down?

I've tried to detach selenium. and I've though that will be enough to allow driver to be detached from gunicorn. But that didn't work out.

I'm updating my code through git and using "systemctl restart gunicorn" to allow it to update.